# how to connect to different WI-FI with static and dynamic IP addresses?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, dhcp

How to connect to different WI-FI with static and dynamic IP addresses?

I have any user with loptop that connect to Wi-Fi inside Co and I set static IP for them

But when users go to their home and connect to home Wi-Fi, they can't connect to internet,  until they change IP to dynamic (DHCP)

What is the solution for this problem ?

Comment: What OS?  Windows, macOS, Linux?

Comment: win 10 64 bite - ver 1903

Answer (score 2):

If you want a user to always have the same IP Address within the company, but also have the freedom to use dynamic addressing at other locations, then the best way to do that is leave the computer at default settings - DHCP automatic - & instead reserve the address on your router* using the computer's MAC address.

That way, the computer 'thinks' it's dynamic, but the router always hands it the same reserved address.

*You'll have to check the manual for exactly how to do this, but it's a fairly common feature.

Comment: Is don't have other solution ?

Comment: You can change the location awareness of every computer one at a time, or you can set up fixed addresses in the router in 5 minutes flat. Most routers you can just find the current connection & set it to 'fixed' or 'static'. Best long-term is to set up your static pool outside your dynamic pool, so there's no potential for conflicts.

Comment: but I set Static Ip for all device

Comment: …but you set it on the computer… which as you have found isn't the best method.

Answer (score 1):

If you're the administrator of that first network, I would argue that the solution is to stop forcing your users to use static IP configuration in the first place.

Instead, set up DHCP and assign *static leases* (aka DHCP reservations) based on each user's MAC address or DHCP Client ID. That way you will still have static addresses for everyone, but your users won't need to change their configuration at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can set static or dynamic IP based on Wi-Fi SSID.

Go to *Settings > Network and Internet > Wi-Fi* and select *"Manage known networks"*

Select the SSID of your network, then *Properties* and click "Edit" under IP Settings and set it to *"Manual"*

You can then set a static IP for just your work Wi-Fi SSID and leave the others automatic.

[image: Settings]

Comment: tnx
**some laptops don't have this setting
and Some other laptops that have these settings ,Error message "failed to set ip static message again"
And every time I do, repeats the same message again**